# how to write a Query Function to Summarize some info from "Data" sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

In cell B1, how to write a Query Function to Summarize some info from "Data" sheet, When I paste any Product Serial number into A2:A9999 , it would shows how many "Returns" and how many "Order Placed" for this Product Serial number.

The result should be as follow:

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/112bNvwv6shGZkHi1MJcWLsuM--mf57MEdqcMjZCQwBc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `Returns` and `Order Placed` are based on what data? Is it possible to clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `QUERY`.

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Summary"; IF(A2:A="",, "Returns:"&COUNTIFS(Data!B2:B,A2:A,Data!F2:F,"*Return*")&"  |  Orders Placed:"&COUNTIF(Data!B2:B,A2:A))})`

This formula generates the header and all column results using fairly straightforward `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: Thank you Erik.   It works

Comment: You're welcome.